# How to turn a program into a screensaver

Tags: windows-xp, windows-10, screensaver, windows-98, windows-2000

I have this event in which I have several computers set up, and I want it so that they use [this](http://panthema.net/2013/sound-of-sorting/) program as their screensaver. What I mean by this is the program will run like normal, but as a screensaver. In this case I want it to go through the algorithms, except bogo and bozo sort, and when the screensaver goes through all of the algorithms, it goes back to the beginning of the list and does it again. I this possible, or is there a screensaver that looks identical and does what I described?

Answer (score 0):

If its going to run the same sequence then you could run it once while recording the video.
And then you could use the video as a screensaver with [dreamscene](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-make-video-screensavers-wallpapers-windows/)(has to be enabled after win7), or even better you could run the video as a livewallpaper (it would be easier to sync all pcs) multiple programs out there for that

Comment: But isn't dreamscene Vista or newer? Aren't all of those Vista or newer?

Comment: I'm sorry but you did not specify the OS on your post, you only spammed the tags with xp/10/98/00

Comment: I need something for 98+